# Exception in an Object toString() command in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, object-to-string

Ok, so I have searched through a massive amount of other questions about the same thing but somehow none of those solutions have worked for my problem. So here is my problem, my Android-App crashes as soon as it has to get the text from an EditText to a String. I have my "Main"-Activity here:

```
package ign.test.fre;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView; 

public class testfre extends Activity {
    public static String cv = "";
    public static String cm = "";
    public static String cz = "";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        //OTHER DEFINITIONS

    EditText ev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v);
    final Spinner em =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.m);
    final Spinner ez = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.z);
    final Button ee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GO);

         //LOTS OF SPINNER STUFF

    ee.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(initialsetup == false){
                enter = true;
                run();
            }
        }
    });
    ev.setOnKeyListener(new AdapterView.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            int key = event.getKeyCode();
            if(key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                enter = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });     
    initialsetup = false;
}
public void run(){
        if(enter == true){
        Calc.Test0();                               
        Calc.Test1_se();                            
        Calc.Test2_etre();                                  
        Calc.Test3_irr();                               
            if(Test3_irr == false){

        //MORE CODE

        textview6.setText("" + ausgabezeile[5]);      
        }   
    }
}
```

My Calc-Class looks like this:
    package ign.test.fre;

```
public class Calc {

   public static void Test0(){
      testfre.cv = testfre.ev.getText().toString();
      testfre.cm = Data.m()[testfre.em.getSelectedItemPosition()];
      testfre.cz = Data.zeiten()[testfre.ez.getSelectedItemPosition()];
      testfre.cv = testfre.cv.toLowerCase();
      testfre.per1.setText(Data.personen()[0]);
      //...
   }
   public static void Test1_se(){
     //MORE CODE
```

and it's in the first 3 lines of the Test0() that there's a problem. It dosen't matter which of those lines is first or where in the code they are it's always them. Even moving them to the run() or onClick() didn't change anything.

My xml-layout looks like this:

```
<android:weightSum="1">
<EditText android:text="Enter Text" android:id="@+id/v" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></EditText>

<Spinner android:layout_width="100dp" android:id="@+id/m" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/v" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Spinner>
<Button android:id="@+id/GO" android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="GO" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/z" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
<Spinner android:layout_width="150dp" android:id="@+id/z" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/v" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/m"></Spinner>
```

My Logcat-entry looks like this (ignian.lomoko.french is the same as ign.test.fre and so forth):

```
10-25 11:58:41.028: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-25 11:58:41.028: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 11:58:41.028: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-25 11:58:41.028: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(316):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-25 11:58:41.028: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(316):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-25 11:58:41.028: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(316):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 11:58:41.038: WARN/ActivityManager(61):      Force finishing activity ignian.lomoko.french/.lomokofrench
10-25 11:58:41.558: WARN/ActivityManager(61):      Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{405c6018 ignian.lomoko.french/.lomokofrench}
10-25 11:58:43.698: INFO/Process(316):             Sending signal. PID: 316 SIG: 9
10-25 11:58:43.708: INFO/ActivityManager(61):      Process ignian.lomoko.french (pid 316) has died.
10-25 11:58:43.708: INFO/WindowManager(61):        WIN DEATH: Window{40691bd8 ignian.lomoko.french/ignian.lomoko.french.lomokofrench paused=false}
10-25 11:58:43.809: WARN/InputManagerService(61):  Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 316 uid 10034
10-25 11:58:52.691: WARN/ActivityManager(61):      Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{405c6018 ignian.lomoko.french/.lomokofrench}
```

Thanks for any help upfront as I can seriously not find any kind of solution anywhere else. The problem as I understand it upto now with the help of others is that I can't access my variables from my "Calc"-Class. What I'm looking for I guess is a way to make the Spinners and EditText public.

Well I followed the solution from dten and now it works!

Comment: Could you please share the logs in logcat at that point of time ?

Comment: sure, give me a minute, thanks

Comment: done, is it enough? and sorry that the names aren't exactly the same.

Comment: Also make sure that you Use standard notations for class names.

Comment: What does that mean exactly? Sorry if that's kinda a dumb question.

Comment: @IgnianSoft: Kartik meant,you should have used TestFre as class name instead of using testfre.That is standard notation for class name.

Comment: oh, Thanks. In my normal code it should be like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are SO many problems with this code it's hard to know where to start

There are statics you then make duplicate variables for in a method but then try reference outside

You're referencing one static from your testfre (which should have a capitcal letter for a name) which you don't mean to be static but you seem to have set to be static because your Calc methods are static

you're referencing things from testfre in your calc class that dont'# even exist in testfre

it's one insane mess

why do you set a keylistener rathen than use on keydown

setting text on your edittext that is in your activity from a static class?

please give variables proper names not just 1 letter

what is Test3_irr  and textview6?

... more to come

```
public class TestFre extends Activity {

    private EditText ev;
    private Spinner em;
    private Spinner ez;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v);
        em = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.m);
        ez = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.z);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.GO:
            runCalculateAndSetText();
        }
    }

    private void runCalculateAndSetText() {

        String word = ev.getText().toString();
        int spinner1pos = em.getSelectedItemPosition();
        int spinner2pos = ez.getSelectedItemPosition();

        if ("".equals(word))
            return;
        if (spinner1pos < 0)
            return;
        if (spinner2pos < 0)
            return;

        // run evaluation for Je and populate textview
        String result = Calc.evaluateJe(word, spinner1pos, spinner2pos);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultJe)).setText(result);

        // run evaluation for Tu and populate textview
        String result = Calc.evaluateJe(word, spinner1pos, spinner2pos);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTu)).setText(result);

        // run evaluation for Il Elle On and populate textview
        String result = Calc.evaluateJe(word, spinner1pos, spinner2pos);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultIllElleOn)).setText(result);

        // Continue for rest of options

    }
}
```

please add

```
onClick="onClick"
```

to your button in the XML (this will call onClick in the activity)

Your Calc class should be able to take the word you've typed and the select box index  (you seem to be getting the value this relates to from somewhere else) and return you the string to fill the textview

The important thing is your Calc class should know NOTHING about your Activity

Comment: Can you give an outline of what you want it to do? I am trying to rewrite it

Comment: well from the EditText and the 2 Spinners the selected Index/written Text has to be inserted into the cv/cz/cm variables as the rest of the Calc_Methods are platform independent and I would like it if only Test0() and the "Main"-class needed to be changed between the platforms. So, the user types somewhat (1 word) and chooses two choices. Out of this information the run() runs the Calc Methods as needed. at the end the calculated information is displayed. Everything works apart from getting the info from the user into those variables. Thanks for you work anyway.

Comment: your Calc stuff doesn't looks very "platform independent"

Comment: So you want to
1. type a word, 2. select a word, 3. select another word. 4. press run and have the result of some method that took the first three on the screen?

Comment: there're over 5000 lines of code in the other Test1-11() which rely on the variables cv/cm/cz which are platform independent. Only the things which are ev/em/ez or the display are different for every platform (has to be). And yes pretty much that is what it's supposed to do.

Comment: If you want it to be platform independent don't add that shit into it :) I've written you something

Comment: ok, first up thanks, many many times. Test3_irr() is part of Calc and does a database check with cv. All textviews are for the result after everything has been calculated. For the pc platform it's kinda done so you know what it does exactly. [link](http://http://www.mediafire.com/lomokofrench) Use the version 0.4.9.1pb the others are worse xD. It's work in progress.

Comment: Thanks a ton, even if I don't use the evaluate way it's fixed my problem and I'll post how I did it exactly later xD. If you wanna know when this app is finished like our facebook page. Thx again, if you want to be mentioned in the credits just tell me. You've been a massive help!

Comment: Although I currently have a problem that I can't start the app anymore. "attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed". Help???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891389/app-cannot-start-at-all-in-android-2-2-froyo this says there is a problem in your manifest. You can put me in the credits though, that would be cool hehe :) check that your Activity class name matches the one in your manifest, (I capitalized it?)

Comment: that's not the problem, it's somewhere in the onCreate Class. I have more than what's up there but not much anymore.

Comment: post the full error in your question at the bottom and I'll try figure it

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 14:42:28.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
10-25 14:42:28.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(457):     at ignian.lomoko.french.lomokofrench.<init>(lomokofrench.java:30)

Comment: Look at line 30 in lomokofrench, it can't find the view you're trying to get

Comment: private EditText ev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v);
    private Spinner em = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.m);
    private Spinner ez = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.z);
That would be the problem...

Comment: you have them in both... so only in the onCreate(). Is cool xD

Comment: see answers, i've changed them to hjust be private EditText ev; etc

Comment: yea my bad :) just in onCreate, or android can't find them yet

Answer (score 1):

One problem i see in your code is you are declaring the objects twice.

See in your activity you took

```
public static EditText ev;
public static Spinner em;
public static Spinner ez;
```

and inside onCreate of Activity you are again doing the same thing :

```
EditText ev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v);
final Spinner em =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.m);
final Spinner ez = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.z);
```

Try replacing above code with below one in onCreate of testfre Activity :

```
ev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v);
em =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.m);
ez = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.z);
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant with EditText/Spinner in front of those lines because otherwise Eclipse that ev/em/ez can't be resolved to a variable. Like this, I can't access those variable from my Calc-Class or from any other classes and I can't make it public ):. I think that's my actual problem. That the Calc-Class can't access my variables and redefining them in the Calc-Class dosen't work either ("The Method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Calc")